# Installing tkinter Python package in QGIS

Tags: qgis, installation, syntaxerror, tkinter

I am trying to install tkinter so I can open a window, but I get an error.

Does someone have a step-by-step process on how to install modules in Python console of QGIS?

Error:

```
>>> python -m pip install tkinter
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python -m pip install tkinter
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

[image]

Comment: Do really need to install "tkinter" to open a window ? You are already in QGIS with the Qt library to create dialog. But indeed, your error, your are mixing bash command versus Python command. in QGIS, you only a Python console allowing Python command.

Answer (score 2):

The console you have in the screenshot is not QGIS's Python console but the OSGeo4W shell. Please update the question accordingly.

You then tried to run a "`python`" command *inside* a Python interpreter.

To install packages with `pip`, you should be in a normal shell (so don't enter `python` after you open the OSGeo4W shell), then `python -m pip install example` will work.

Like @etrimaille said, if you are going to develop something related to QGIS, stay away from `tkinter` but use the Qt bindings (`qgis.PyQt`).

Comment: but is there a script for generating a window for like a "save as"?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html

Comment: Tkinter can be installed as a Osgeo4w package using setup.exe and advanced install. See: https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/