# Installing tkinter in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, tkinter, geosoft

I have found questions where this has been asked, but not a clear solution.

I am trying to use [Geosoft API](https://github.com/GeosoftInc/gxpy) functions from a QGIS plugin. Although it is not shown as a dependency, `tkinter` seems to be a prerequisite unless I misunderstand.  I have no interest in tkinter, per se.

**Problem**

I installed `geosoft` library from OSGeo4W Shell using `pip`. If I type the following from OSGeo4W Shell, all looks good.

`pip show geosoft`

It tells me that there are three required libraries: `numpy`, `pandas` and `requests`:

```
Name: geosoft
Version: 2023.2.0
Summary: Geosoft GX API module for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/GeosoftInc/gxpy
Author: Geosoft Inc.
Author-email: support@geosoft.com
License: BSD
Location: c:\program files\qgis 3.28.8\apps\python39\lib\site-packages
Requires: numpy, pandas, requests
```

However, if I execute the following line from a QGIS plugin...

```
import geosoft.gxpy as gxpy
```

... I get errors:

```
import geosoft.gxpy as gxpy
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.8/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.8\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\geosoft\gxpy\__init__.py", line 3, in 
from . import gx
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.8/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.8\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\geosoft\gxpy\gx.py", line 17, in 
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.8/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.8\apps\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 37, in 
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.8/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

Sure enough, **QGIS 3.28.8\apps\Python39\Lib\site-packages\geosoft\gxpy\gx.py** contains this statement at line 17:

`import tkinter.ttk as ttk`

As a test I substitute the 'geosoft' import with `import tkinter as tk` in my code. Again it fails. I understand that this is because QGIS doesn't come installed with `tkinter`.

So I conclude that `tkinter` is required, and that I haven't got it.

**Solution?**

Andreas Müller's comment [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/458181/installing-tkinter-python-package-in-qgis) indicates that it can be installed by running Osgeo4w Setup and using Advanced Install. I have tried this but am not entirely sure what to do.

I can run **C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.8\bin\osgeo4w-setup.exe**

But:

- I have to specify the root install directory. It is already
  installed. So I am not sure whether I should be replacing the
  existing installation or doing something else.
- I have to specify the local package directory. Not sure where this
  should be.
- I am prompted to select packages to install, but although there are
  plenty to choose from there is not one called `tkinter`. The only one that looks close is `python3-tcltk`. That is described as 'Python
  Tkinter and IDLE', but it is under the category
  `Commandline_Utilities`, which isn't what I would really have
  expected.

Is this the right way of going about it, or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem by using the Osgeo4w Setup Advanced Install as advised in [the post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/458181/installing-tkinter-python-package-in-qgis) I referred to in the question. I was a bit concerned about doing this without really knowing what I was doing, but it doesn't seem to have broken anything.

With the caveat that I doubt this is the optimal way, what I did was this:

- Ran Osgeo4w Setup
- Selected Advance Install
- Left the installation folder as the default: 'C:\OSGeo4W'
- Left the local package directory as the default
- When prompted for download site, chose the top one (osgeo.org)
- When prompted for library, selected `python3-tcltk`
- Next page told me that there were 11 x unmet dependencies, so opted to install them as well.
- This generated a set of files and folders in 'C:\OSGeo4W'. At this point I still got the error in QGIS.
- With QGIS closed, I then copied the whole contents of 'C:\OSGeo4W' to the QGIS program folder 'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.8', overwriting where they already existed. This stopped the error.

It may be that I should have directed Osgeo4w Setup straight to the QGIS program folder. I tried this but it wouldn't accept the path since there is a space in the name. (And it may be that using 8.3 name convention would have got around this; I didn't try it.)

Incidentally, from OSGeo4W Shell, `pip list` still does not show `tkinter` or anything obviously related to it. But it looks as if Python is finding it.